# Why are the labels not displaying the correct (virtual) attribute values?

Tags: qgis, labeling, virtual-field

1. I have a polygon and I create a new field `area_ha` using this expression in the field calculator:
   `round( $area /10000,1)`

   When I use that field for my labels, everything is fine and works as it should work:

   [image]
2. I create a new field, but this time a virtual field with the name `"area_ha_virtual_field"`. I use the same expression in the field calculator. The resulting value in the attribute table is fine. But when I want to use that new virtual field to label my blue polygon, it shows a totally different number than in my attribute table:

   [image]
3. Also, I get that same weird number as a label, when I use that expression in my labeling properties:

   [image]

My CRS is 25832.

Comment: What is QGIS version? I use v 3.16 and there is no problem.

Comment: have you tried `area($geometry)` instead of `$area`?

Comment: @Erik: round(area($geometry)/10000,1) did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Erik suggested: When I use `round(area($geometry)/10000,1)` instead of `round( $area /10000,1)` the virtual values are displayed correctly as labels.